# Button dropdown in search form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

With twitter bootstrap, I know you can prepend and append buttons to a text input.  Can I prepend a button *dropdown*?

Here is the twitter bootstrap form input documentation: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Here's the section for button dropdowns: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns

Comment: What exactly do you mean by button dropdown, can you provide a mocku-up?

Comment: @markus-tharkun Button dropdowns are a part of twitter bootstrap.  I will add a link to the documentation for it.

Comment: ok, so you want to prepend a button dropdown to a text input... hm, why? and have you tried, how did you fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  All you have to do is make sure the outer div of the button dropdown group has the same display property (in my case, `inline-block`) and the same vertical alignment (in my case, `middle`) as its siblings (the text input and any other buttons).